# Hom-set of ind-objects of the same shape

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits

The usual definition of hom-sets between ind-objects in a category $C$ is:

$$
\operatorname{ind-}C(F,G) := \lim{}_{a\in A} \operatorname{colim}_{b\in B} \operatorname{Hom}(Fa,Gb)\;.
$$

where $F:A\to C$ and $G:B\to C$ are ind-objects, i.e. functors from filtered categories.

Now suppose that $A=B$.

> Can we interchange the order of limit and colimit?

Comment: No. Just take any example of, say, a sequential limit and colimit not commuting, and then make those your Hom sets. E.g. Z/(p^k). Take colimit first then limit, you get zero. Take limit first then colimit and you get Q_p.

Comment: @DylanWilson: This is not a *comment*.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b9/MagrittePipe.jpg